# Nginx mapping with transparent port/proxy(?)

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, lets-encrypt

I'm not entirely sure what it is I'm looking for here, so I'm not able to effectively search for my answer.

I'm using [dehydrated](https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated) for LetsEncrypt's TLS-ALPN challenges. I'm hosting the service behind nginx by using

```
stream {
    map $ssl_preread_alpn_protocols $tls_port {
        ~\bacme-tls/1\b 10443;
        default 3443;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:$tls_port;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 3443 ssl;
    listen [::]:3443 ssl;

    server_name wanderingwerners.com www.wanderingwerners.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/my/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/privkey.pem;

    index index.html;
    root /var/www/wanderingwerners.com/;
}
```

This works pretty great - I can get new certs with zero downtime, and my website is accessible. However, when I access my page it works fine. When I hover over a link it shows me https://www.wanderingwerners.com/a-beginning/

Clicking on that link, though, takes me to https://www.wanderingwerners.com:3443/a-beginning/

This is undesirable - I'd prefer it show up as plain ol' https://www.wanderingwerners.com/a-beginning/

I'm assuming that something I have setup here in nginx is what's causing the confusion, but I'm not positive.

Is there a way that I can update my nginx config to still allow the dehydrated server to work, but also tell the browser that `:3443` isn't *really* what they should be connecting to? (Or at least, don't show it in the address bar)

**Update**

When I do `curl https://www.wanderingwerners.com/a-beginning` it gives me a 301 redirect. Something is definitely happening with my nginx config here.

**Another Update**

When I do `curl https://www.wanderingwernerx.com/a-beginning/` it works just fine so it looks like it's doing something with the trailing `/`

Comment: The example URL you gave works fine. Are you still actually having a problem?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes - click on that, and then click on the home link on the bottom and you *should* see what I mean. Unless it's just working weird from my local machine :P

Comment: Works for me. Clear your browser cache.

Comment: try `curl https://www.wanderingwerners.com/a-beginning` and you should get the redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect you described comes from nginx when you omitted the trailing slash from a URL. You should be able to suppress it with `port_in_redirect off;`.

Comment: It's still showing up - I've placed it in the `http` block, in the `server` block for wanderingwerners, and still getting `< Location: https://www.wanderingwerners.com:3443/a-beginning/
` after an `nginx -s reload`

Comment: Oh huh. a full blown server restart seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your web site software running on port 3443 is generating links in its HTML code that include the port number.

You need to find a way for the software to generate links pointing to the domain without the port number.

Another change I suggest for you is:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:3443 ssl;

    server_name wanderingwerners.com www.wanderingwerners.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/my/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/privkey.pem;

    index index.html;
    root /var/www/wanderingwerners.com/;
}
```

With this configuration port 3443 is not exposed outside your server, it is only reachable from the server itself. Applying this configuration means that you need to fix the previous issue first.

Comment: it's static html, so it doesn't know anything about ports

Comment: That's definitely not (just) it. When I change it to `127.0.0.1:3443` the initial connection works fine, but subsequent clicks.... oh hey! Looks like there's a 301 redirect -_-